# Exercise $\textrm{3.2.O}$ from Vakil's notes on AG: Is this statement/picture correct? How to interpret a map of spaces as a map between Spectrums?

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra, intuition

> [image]

---

I'm not sure why we should picture this as a map from a parabola to a line. Shouldn't this be the other way around?

**We have that $x \mapsto x^2$, so shouldn't the picture be from a line to a parabola?**

---

Also since $\mathbb C \to \mathbb C$ sends $x \mapsto y=x^2$, is this the same as a map $\operatorname{Spec} \mathbb C[t] \to \operatorname{Spec} \mathbb C[t]$ where $(t-x) \mapsto (t-x^2)$ ?

Comment: Yes, basically it's mapping from the straight horizontal $x$-line to the graph (parabola) and then projects it to the $y$-axis. Note, however, that $x\mapsto (x,f(x))$ is an isomorphism/homeomorphism to the line, with inverse $(x,y)\mapsto x$.